# Open port 8080 on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I already did the configuration as the documentation sends and the door does not open.

Firewall Rules Config[image]
Netstat on server[image]
Nmap[image]

Comment: Hi Joao, have you configured the [egress firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) too? Keep in mind that you need to check the OS firewall within your instance, apart from the Google Cloud Platform firewall rules too.

Comment: You do not have a process running that is listening on TCP IPv4 Port 8080. You do have a process listening on IPv6 port 8080.

Comment: In my case, ubuntu running firewalll, disabling it let me continue my work: `sudo ufw disable`

Answer (score 0):

Google Firewall rules are for just to allow traffic to the instance. In your case, seems you have to open the port 8080 from the server level.